# Variable naming in Python classes

Tags: python, class, scope

So I started using python very recently. I am doing a small project involving classes. I for the most part have the conventions down like using self... etc.  What I haven't figured out quite yet is the name mangling which may be related to my question.

Here is some code that forms a class to create a turn object that i can intilize in the beginning of a battle and allows me to switch turns periodically. (the game is going to be a pokemon battle simulator)

```
class turn:

    TURNS = ("player","computer")
    curr=0

    def __init__(self): 
        self.currentTurn=turn.TURNS[turn.curr]

    def getTurn(self):
        return turn.TURNS[turn.curr]

    def switch(self):
        if turn.curr == 0: 
            turn.curr = 1 
        else:   
            turn.curr = 0

        if turn.curr==0: 
            print "It's your move! \n"

        self.currentTurn=TURNS[turn.curr]
```

So my question is this:

Is there any feature of python that would allow me to omit the class name when referring to the class vairables. I feel like it should know to look within the class definition for those variables but it doesn't. Also, If I want to use a helper method within the same class, i seem to have to prefix that with self.

Is there anyway around this?

Comment: Martjin, I was in the midst of editing when you fixed the errors for me, thank you. The SO editor put those stars in for me when I tried to make all the instances of "turn." bold

Comment: "Explicit is better than implicit."  Live with Python's dogmas like this one.  What might appear as a nice feature to you might be a lot of trouble for the next developer trying to understand your code.

Comment: @user3756732: There is no support for formatting in a code block; outside a codeblock `**` makes things bold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference the current class with [`type(self)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) or [`self.__class__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#instance.__class__). Take into account that that value changes as a class is subclassed.

So:

```
class turn(object):
    def __init__(self): 
        cls = type(self)
        self.currentTurn = cls.TURNS[cls.curr]

    def getTurn(self):
        cls = type(self)
        return cls.TURNS[cls.curr]

    def switch(self):
        cls = type(self)
        cls.curr = 1 - cls.curr

        if cls.curr == 0: 
            print "It's your move! \n"

        self.currentTurn = cls.TURNS[cls.curr]
```

but if you were to subclass `turns`, then *setting* `cls.curr` will be done on the subclass, not the `turn` parent class when you call `subclass().switch()`.

You can also use the `self.__class__` attribute, but using a built-in function lets you keep the code more readable.

However, note that as long as there are no instance attributes with the same names, you can refer to your class attributes *on `self` as well*; the following works too:

```
class turn(object):
    def __init__(self): 
        self.currentTurn = self.TURNS[self.curr]

    def getTurn(self):
        return self.TURNS[self.curr]

    def switch(self):
        cls = type(self)
        cls.curr = 1 - cls.curr

        if self.curr == 0: 
            print "It's your move! \n"

        self.currentTurn = self.TURNS[self.curr]
```

*Setting* class attributes still requires that you do so directly on the class, not `self`, however.

Comment: By "subclassing" you mean if I were to put another class definition within that class?

Comment: @user3756732: you can create a derived class, that reuses everything in `turn`, adding on to it, or replacing functionality. `class subclass(turn): pass` is a useless subclass that just inherited everything without adding.

Comment: @user3756732: see [*Inheritance* in the Python toturial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance).

Comment: @user3756732: Btw, I am making the assumption that you are using Python 3 here; in Python 2, make sure you inherit from `object` (new-style classes), otherwise `type(self)` won't work.

Comment: Thanks this was helpful, and I know about inheritance, that idea just didn't register in my head at the moment, it seemed to obvious lol. Thanks for editing to make more clear